# How do I stop QXmlStreamWriter from escaping quotation marks?

Tags: c++, xml, qt, escaping

Let me begin by expressing my understanding that what I'm trying to do is **not** normal, nor is it typically well advised. I'm fully aware that in normal XML, the `"` character is reserved.

I'm generating `.vcxproj` files to use in Visual Studio 2010, using a Qt application. I'm taking advantage of the `QXmlStreamWriter` class to write the XML needed for the project file. However, I'm running into a problem due to Microsoft's non-compliance with the XML standard.

In `CustomBuild` elements, the user needs to specify the command for building the file. In the case of Qt projects within Visual Studio, you end up with something like this:

```
  <Command Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">"$(QTDIR)\bin\moc.exe"  "%(FullPath)" -o "..\myproj\moc_%(Filename).cpp"  -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_DLL -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_XML_LIB -DQT_SQL_LIB -DQT_OPENGL_LIB -DQT_QT3SUPPORT_LIB -DQT3_SUPPORT -DQT_SVG_LIB "-I." "-I$(QTDIR)\include" "-I$(QTDIR)\include\QtCore" "-I$(QTDIR)\include\QtGui" "-I$(QTDIR)\include\QtXml" "-I$(QTDIR)\include\QtSql" "-I$(QTDIR)\include\QtOpenGL" "-I$(QTDIR)\include\Qt3Support" "-I$(QTDIR)\include\QtSvg" "-I$(QTDIR)\include\QtTest" "-I..\myproj"</Command>
```

Yucky, but *c'est la vie*, especially with Microsoft. Unfortunatey, my `QXmlStreamWriter` object produces this (fully compliant) output:

```
  <Command Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">$(QTDIR)\bin\moc.exe&quot; &quot;%(FullPath)&quot; -o &quot;..\myproj\moc_%(Filename).cpp&quot;   -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_DLL -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_XML_LIB -DQT_SQL_LIB -DQT_OPENGL_LIB -DQT_QT3SUPPORT_LIB -DQT3_SUPPORT -DQT_SVG_LIB &quot;-I.&quot; &quot;-I$(QTDIR)\include&quot; &quot;-I$(QTDIR)\include\QtCore&quot; &quot;-I$(QTDIR)\include\QtGui&quot; &quot;-I$(QTDIR)\include\QtXml&quot; &quot;-I$(QTDIR)\include\QtSql&quot; &quot;-I$(QTDIR)\include\QtOpenGL&quot; &quot;-I$(QTDIR)\include\Qt3Support&quot; &quot;-I$(QTDIR)\include\QtSvg&quot; &quot;-I$(QTDIR)\include\QtTest&quot; &quot;..\myproj&quot;</Command>
```

Naturally, Visual Studio isn't impressed. What are my options here? I could probably read back the file and un-escape it, but that doesn't sound particularly efficient or intelligent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you are using `QXmlStreamWriter::writeCharacters` or similar to write the strings which contain `"` ?

Perhaps, before calling that function, you could check if the string you are about to write contains `"`.  If it does, you could split it on `"`, write the non-`"` characters via `QXmlStreamWriter::writeCharacters`, and write `"` directly to the underlying `QIODevice`:

```
QString maybeHasQuotes = ...;
QStringList parts = maybeHasQuotes.split('"');
while (!parts.isEmpty()) {
    QString part = parts.takeFirst();
    writer.writeCharacters(part);
    if (!parts.isEmpty()) {
        writer.device()->putChar('"');
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I'm using the `writeCharacters()` method. That's a pretty good idea. I'll give it a shot in the morning at work and follow up.

Comment: Bingo. That did it. I added my own answer for completion's sake.

Answer (score 1):

Bypassing straight to the `QIODevice` the way @rohanpm suggested was the way to go.

I subclassed `QXmlStreamWriter` and added a method to write quoted strings.

## customstreamwriter.h

```
#ifndef CUSTOMSTREAMWRITER_H
#define CUSTOMSTREAMWRITER_H

#include <QXmlStreamWriter>

class CustomStreamWriter : public QXmlStreamWriter
{
public:
    CustomStreamWriter(QIODevice *device);
    void writeQuotedCharacters(QString text);
};

#endif // CUSTOMSTREAMWRITER_H
```

## customstreamwriter.cpp

```
#include "customstreamwriter.h"

CustomStreamWriter::CustomStreamWriter(QIODevice *device) :
    QXmlStreamWriter(device)
{
}

void CustomStreamWriter::writeQuotedCharacters(QString text) {
    QStringList parts = text.split('"');
    while (!parts.isEmpty()) {
        QString part = parts.takeFirst();
        writeCharacters(part);
        if (!parts.isEmpty()) {
            device()->putChar('"');
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of using `QXmlStreamWriter`, I use my `CustomStreamWriter` instead. The only difference is that when I need to write a quoted string, I call my `writeQuotedCharacters()` method.